Calling groovy sql newInstance() with parameters
I'm using Groovy sql library as following:
import groovy.sql.Sql

def url = 'jdbc:mysql://<host>:<port>/<db>'
def username = 'user'
def password = 'pass'
def driver = 'com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'

def sql = Sql.newInstance(url, username, password, driver)

I also need to use a Certificate Authority (CA) certificate file in PEM format to login to the database.
When I use mysql cli I have this flag added to login command --ssl-ca=/path/to/cert.pem.
How can I add cert.pem to Sql.newInstance method?

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-server-authentication.html
